# AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I've been making this simple reddit bot, and it worked fine while I was testing it, but now for some reason it keeps giving me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conniptions.py", line 49, in <module>
    run_bot(r, comments_replied_to)
  File "conniptions.py", line 24, in run_bot
    comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)
AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here's my code: https://hastebin.com/usokoyojig.py

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to solve this for a while but I'm very new in Python so I have run out of ideas.

Comment: You are trying to `.append` to a `filter` object. `filter` objects don't have an `.append` method. A `filter` object is an iterator. You have to materialize it into a list to use `list` methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is it: `filter` returns a "'filter' object", an iterable you can't `append` to. You should convert it to a `list` first.

Comment: `comments_replied_to = []` does this not make it an empty list?

Comment: @IanGermann, it does, but if the file exists, you assign `comments_replied_to = filter(...)`, which is no more a list.